# how to remove space in when using cucumber example placeholder?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I have following test case where i want pass '00:00:00.0' (date_suffix) for one example and one for not.

however using this approach it also append space in first example with no date_suffix

so it results something like this:

// I need to get rid of last space (after /17) for example 1.

```
example1. "1996/06/17 " 

example2. "1996/06/17 00:00:00.0"
```

--

```
Then Some case:
    | birthdate                |
    | 1996/06/17 <date_suffix> |
    | 1987-11-08 <date_suffix> |
    | 1998-07-20 <date_suffix> |


  @example1
  Examples:
    | date_suffix |
    |             |

  @example2
  Examples:
    | date_suffix |
    | 00:00:00.0  |
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible in Gherkin.

However it seems like you are testing a date parser or validation tool through some other component.

By adding the time stamp to the date, you're adding incidental details to your scenario. It is not immediately apparent what these test and maybe overlooked in the future.

Consider instead testing the parser/validator separately and directly.

Once you have confidence in the date parser works correctly, use for your current scenario a list of mixed dates, some with and some without suffix.

Comment: can you give an example ?